# if $a = -1, b \geq 1$ and $f(x) = \frac {1}{|x|}$ then show that conditions of Lagrangian mean value theorem are not satisfied

Tags: calculus

if $a = -1, b \geq 1$ and $f(x) = \frac {1}{|x|}$ then show that conditions of lagrangian mean value theorem are not satisfied but conclusion is true if and only if $b > 1 + \sqrt{2}$

My approach:
$\frac {1}{|x|}$ is not differentialble at x =0. so Lagranges mean value theorem can not be applied. 
For conclusion to be true,

$f^{'}(c) = \frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \implies c|c| = \frac {|b|(b+1)}{|b|-1} \implies c|c| = \frac {b(b+1)}{b-1} $ consider c to be postive and $a<c<b \implies a^2 < c^2 < b^2 \implies \frac {b(b+1)}{b-1} < b^2 $ solving this i got $b > 1+ \sqrt{2}$

But i am not able to prove other direction, given $b > 1+ \sqrt{2}$ how to show that there exists c between $(a,b)$

I am getting following :
$c^2 = \frac {b(b+1)}{ (b-1)} > \frac {(1+\sqrt{2})(2+\sqrt{2})}{b-1}$

After that how should i proceed?